# Whether "illiteracy" is rude or impoliteness internet user name?

Tags: politeness, internet

I want the "illiteracy" name say I'm an `English illiteracy` in other words `Maybe I'm lack English skills to accurate express and understand`, but some people say:

> [And... please, change your name... it really doesn't look very well.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466495/why-grub-mkrescue-doesnt-accept-the-core-compress-xz-option#comment850148_466495)

Comment: I don't think it was appropriate for someone to criticize a made-up Internet name because it "doesn't look well" (that should be "good" not "well"). I do think this is a question we can answer though.

Comment: "I'm *an illiteracy*" isn't correct (although maybe that was your point!)  *Illiteracy* means "the condition of being unable to read or write". You are not the condition of being unable to read or write, you are a person who cannot read or write - you are **an illiterate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expresses too radical self-criticism, since it literally means inability to read or write. You could use instead a more optimistic name of that kind, like '*newbie*'.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, as an English speaker, I find that username actually quite amusing. **I'd keep it if I were you!** And no, it's absolutely not offensive or impolite. The only complaint I could see being raised is that you're calling someone else "illiterate", but as a username, this is ridiculous; usernames almost always reflect oneself, so it's a self-deprecatingly humorous username.